# C++ ESP32 - 86400000000 is printed as 500654080

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-c++

I'm working on a ESP32 using Arduino, for some reason the values are printed differently, what is the cause?

```
auto reset_time = 24L * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000; //86400000000

  Serial.print("Reset Timer in: ");
  Serial.println(reset_time);

  Serial.print((reset_time / 1000));
  Serial.println(" ms");

  Serial.print((reset_time / 1000 / 1000));
  Serial.println(" s");

  Serial.print((reset_time / 1000 / 1000 / 60));
  Serial.println(" m");

  Serial.print((reset_time / 1000 / 1000 / 60 / 60));
  Serial.println(" h");
```

This produces the following output:

```
21:05:58.310 -> Reset Timer in: 500654080
21:05:58.310 -> 500654 ms
21:05:58.310 -> 500 s
21:05:58.310 -> 8 m
21:05:58.310 -> 0 h
```

Comment: Note that `500654080 == 86400000000 % 2**32` You're looking at 32 bit overflow.

Comment: Try using `24LL`.

Comment: You want to wait 1000 days? Do you have an Uninterruptible power supply?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica you caught me there ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

86400000000   Mod   2^32 is 500654080.

The value is larger than fits in a 32 bit int; what you see is the remainder.

If I read a C17 draft correctly, a constant expression that cannot be represented in its type is a constraint violation. It requires a diagnostic message from the compiler:

> 6.6 Constant expressions
> **Constraints**
> [...]
> 4 Each constant expression shall evaluate to a constant
> that is in the range of representable values for
> its type.

> 5.1.1.3 Diagnostics
> 1 A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-
> defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation
> of any syntax rule or constraint,

Comment: Does the standard have anything to say about the truncation of out-of-bounds compile time constants?  Is that a guaranteed result?